# Choosing server based on location for NordVPN

Tags: vpn

So. I got NordVPN because it had a lot of server options in the United States. I am a Linux user (Ubuntu) and the nice GUI that comes with the Windows version is not available. I tried exploring all the command line options and saw no option to display a list of servers. I can also find nowhere in their website a full current list of servers and their corresponding cities. I would ultimately be able to choose a city, find a server there and connect directly to that server. Is that an option?

If not, is there another better VPN with that option?

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a couple ways:

- Using the (undocumented) API endpoints of https://nordvpn.com/api/server or https://nordvpn.com/api/server/stats
- Using a script like https://github.com/mrzool/nordvpn-server-find, which will use the API and tell you which servers currently have a low load
- If you're [using OpenVPN directly](https://nordvpn.com/tutorials/linux/openvpn/) (rather than the NordVPN client) you can download the country-coded OVPN configs from https://downloads.nordcdn.com/configs/archives/servers/ovpn.zip (from the NordVPN Linux docs) or https://nordvpn.com/api/files/zip (from the NordVPN OpenWRT docs). I think the only difference is the former separates UDP and TCP into different directories while the latter puts them in the same directory.